# Javascript: Detect a click on the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine whether user clicking element scrollbar or content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/how-to-determine-whether-user-clicking-element-scrollbar-or-content)

Is there a way to detect a click on the scroll bar of the browser window with javascript?

Thanks !

Comment: No, but on scroll will trigger if something moved

Comment: smilar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/how-to-determine-whether-user-clicking-element-scrollbar-or-content with a few suggestions