# Is it possible to bind on the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code right now that looks like this:

```
 $('body').bind('click', someFunction);
```

I want to bind this to the scroll bar as well though (the whole scroll bar area). I haven't found a way to do this yet? Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Nope, other than binding the scroll event, mouse events aren't fired on the scrollbar.

Comment: @adeneo could be using uggly workaround i think

Comment: Isn't scroll event enough?

Comment: Maybe this can thread can be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind on scroll instead. [There are no mouse events on the scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574088/is-it-possible-to-bind-on-the-scroll-bar/17574145#comment25569777_17574088):

```
$(window).bind('scroll', someFunction);
```