# Cancel mousedown event if scrollbar was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scrollbar, target

I have an unordered list with lots of li elements. When clicking (mousedown event) inside the list, I use event.target to determine whether or not an li was clicked. If the target element is the ul, I de-select all the li elements.

However, when clicking on the scrollbar, a mousedown event is also fired and the target element is the ul. But I don't wish to deselect anything by clicking on the scrollbar. So how do I determine whether or not the scrollbar was clicked so I can cancel the event?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. You can only detect the px's that you clicked, and compare that to the document width v.s. the window with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Comment: Oh, I'll have to bodge a solution in that case - maybe I'll ask w3c to add this to the spec ;)

Comment: it can be done.. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can by creating a wrapper div with the same height and width +30px (scrollbar), which has the overflow property. That way when the scrollbar of the new div is clicked it wont trigger the click of the UL.

Comment: I see your point, but it's just as easy to detect whether or not the mousedown event occurred less than 30px from the end using offsetX and clientX etc.

Comment: That might be, but my solution is way cleaner and there is no need for a piece of client-side script here. This solution is more sustainable and more easy to understand for another developer who needs to adjust the code