# click on browser scroll bar close popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

When clicking on browser scroll bar my popop window closed.
I am used this code for closing popup:

```
//Closing the pop up when clicked outside of it.
  $(document).click(function(e) {
     $("#popup").mouseup(function() {
            return false;
     });
          // Bind mouseup event to all the document
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        // Check if the click is outside the popup 
        if($(e.target).parents("#popup").length==0 && !$(e.target).is("#popup") && $(e.target).parents(".calendar").length==0) {
        // Hide the popup
        alert("hi");
        $("#popup").hide();
    }
    });

 });
```

And my popup css is:

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}
.popupDiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(245, 245, 245);
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    padding: 10px 10px 35px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 85px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I need my popup not closed on when I click on browser's scroll bar.

Comment: please add you code on jsfiddle....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Scroll bar Click (Hack code for scrollbar click)

**[FiddleFromReference](http://jsfiddle.net/udFQy/)**

[Determine whether user clicking scrollbar or content (onclick for native scroll bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll)

Check target value

**Only Body:**

```
 $("body").mouseup(function(e) {

    alert("hi");

});
```

**Check particular target**

```
  $(document).click( function (event) {
  var idName = event.target.id;   // Use  event.target.nodeName
  if(idName == "my_link"){
    return false;
  };
  $('#your_div').fadeOut(350);

});
```

**Except Body Content including Scrollbar**

```
 $(window).mouseup(function(e) {
 if (e.target == $('html').get(0)) { // Except body content
 alert("hi"); 
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
       $("#popup").hide();
    });
});
```