# Get click coordinates on document but not the scrollbars

Tags: jquery

How can I get the mouse coordinates on the webpage (not the body as it may be smaller than the viewport) but do not register any scrollbar clicks. This code below also tracks any coordinates from clicks that happen on the scrollbars and I don't want that

```
$(document).bind('mousedown', function(evt) {
        var x = evt.pageX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        var y = evt.pageY + document.body.scrollTop;

});
```

Comment: When you say "do not register any scrollbar clicks", do you mean just the window's scrollbar? Or do you mean any scrollbar on any overflowing block level element such as a div?

Comment: only the window's scrollbar

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Comment: unfortunately, no. the browser scrollbar is not a document element. but i don't really care about noticing the click but rather neglecting it... is the only possibility to hardcode the scrollbars for specific browsers? :(