# Remove event on scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a scroll-able div in which I have added some contents
I want to trigger an event if user clicks inside this DIV.
**HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    ... some content..
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    var clickedElemet = $(e.target);
    if(clickedElemet.is($("#mainDiv"))){
      alert("mainDiv clicked"); // alert is getting called if we click on scrollbar
    }
})
```

Now the problem is when user click on scroll bar handle , Event is getting fired.
Any suggestion how can I prevent event if user clicks on scroll bar handle.?
Please note that this works fine if I use **CLICK** event.

> Please note that I can not change DOM structure and have to use mousedown event only.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsvishal/qhwcp98t/)

Comment: I would make an outer div that is scrollable and have a slightly thinner div inside with the on click action.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Comment: Actually I can not change the DOM structure. This is the main problem. :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qhwcp98t/1/

Comment: @Vishu238 please add this important detail on your question, a several number of answer were based on changing your HTML structure...

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @Vishu238 If your problem solved and my answer were useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get click `X position` then check that click `X position` is out of scrollbar `X position`.

See demo in **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhwcp98t/10/)**.

*Note: this doesn't work properly in browser zoom in and zoom out.*