# How to prevent scroll event from firing after adjusting `scrollTop` when mouse pulls up scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar

I’m trying to push the scrollbar down a few px when the user scrolls to the top of the `<div>`. The problem is that after the scroll is pushed down a few px (after I scroll to the top) the browser still thinks that my mouse is at the top of the `<div>` when my mouse is still held down (`mousedown`). This is bad as the event keeps firing.

Features I am trying to achieve:

1. Scroll to the top of the `<div>`
2. Scroll gets pushed down a few pixels but the function does not fire again even if my mouse is still on mouse down.

I think it may be the way I detect the function through `onscroll`. Please test my code and see the `console.log()` if I am not making sense.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('scroll-box');
wrapper.onscroll = function (evt){
  //detect when scroll has reached the top of the frame
  if(wrapper.scrollTop === 0){
      console.log('top of frame');
      wrapper.scrollTop += 500;
  }

  //detect when scroll has reached the bottom of the frame
  if(wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.scrollTop === wrapper.clientHeight){
    console.log('bottom of frame');
  }
}

wrapper.scrollTop += 3000;
```

```css
.scroll-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
  
div ul li {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-box" id="scroll-box">
  <ul>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
    <li>messages</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to do..?
your code running good and display value in console.

Comment: if you hold the mouse down and drag it to the top of the div, the scroll gets pushed down as expected but the browser still thinks the scroll is at the top of the div on mouse down. you can see it through the console.log('top of frame'). For example scroll to the top and move the mouse a little to the top or bottom and the console gets filled  console.log('top of frame'); even when the scroll has already been pushed down.

Comment: You could check and see if the mouse is down on anything except the scroll bar; if it is on something other then the scroll bar and the mouse is down, just prevent the default scroll event? Does this make sense?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/33799265/3011082

Comment: That is to determine if the scroll bar was clicked on an element.

Comment: the detection of the scroll at the top of the div should not even fire though on the scroll bar as the scroll would be pushed down. Can reccomend you to try out a chat application like facebook messenger, when you scroll to the top, new messages load and the scroll is pushed down and the on mouse down event is deactivated as I have to click again to use the scroll.

Comment: It's logical it keeps on firing as you would be dragging it to the top again each time it gets scrolled down. But the interesting part would be how to cancel the mousedown. So far I think you can't.

Comment: yeah, not sure how existing chat applications are doing it. because after new data is loaded the mouse event is cancelled.

Comment: Here's a dirty workaround : [**Link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rObGrJ?editors=001).

Comment: Cheers, you could make it a bit less noticeable by changing the width of the element temporarily as well. Another solution could be to create your own scrollbar, you'll have full control over the events then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the fact that the event will keep on firing and logging that the div is at the top is a natural result from it being pushed down and then dragged up again rapidly because the scrollbar hasn't been released. As far as I can see, there's no direct way to cancel that interaction.

But without creating a custom scrollbar this is probably the quickest fix, even if it is a minor hack :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjPqYp?editors=001)

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('scroll-box'),
size = wrapper.clientWidth;

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  if (!wrapper.scrollTop) {
    console.log('top of frame');
    wrapper.scrollTop += 500;
    wrapper.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + size + 'px; overflow: hidden');
    setTimeout(function() {
      wrapper.removeAttribute('style');
    }, 0);
  }
});

wrapper.scrollTop += 200;
```

Eliminating the scroll event by hiding overflow for the shortest possible amount of time. And setting `clientWidth` of the element as well to make it keep it's original width so the action is less noticeble.