# Jquery scrollbar selector

Tags: jquery

I'm working on image gallery project, my problem is when an image is displayed i want to hide it when i click outside the image container. 
I use this code to do that, but my is when i click on scrollbar the image is hidden, and i don't want that. i want to add body scrollbar to the code so when i click on it the image doesn't hide.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $("#overlay_info");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
  {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Someone please flag as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Comment: @Gothdo please read the question again, i guess you didn't understand it

Comment: You want to dismiss clicks on scrollbar, and the question I linked is about determining if scrollbar have been clicked or not. Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: @Gothdo yes you didn't understand my question. what i want is to make the code work and what exist in the link you provide doesn't work in this case. if you sure about your reponse then please make my code to work.

Comment: Now I guess you didn't understand the question I linked.

Comment: @Gothdo i understand the question you linked. my question is scrollbar selector. something like this   `$("#overlay_info, body_scrollbar")` so i can use it to not hide image container if some one click on them. i hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such selector, because scrollbars are not part of website, but of browser interface. You can't select it with JavaScript or jQuery for the same reason you can't access browser window's close button.

Comment: so how facebook can do that?

Comment: @ler Facebook can't too.

Comment: did you try it? you wrong. .click on any picture on facebook and then click on scrollbar the picture will not hide. i want the samething.

Comment: @ler They managed to achieve this in a different way than you think, probably similar to the answer I linked.