# Detect mousedown/click event on browser's scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that with the jQuery expression `$(element).on("mousedown", function(evt) { ... });` you can handle `mousedown` events on an element.

Though I need to detect the `mousedown` or `click` event on the browser's scroll bar and need to run some function.

Comment: Here there are multiple answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Comment: this is related to scroll count but i am looking for click or mousedwon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest capturing the mousedown event and testing for the coordinates. If the coordinates are greater than or equal to the visible document body width, they clicked in the scrollbar area!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.target === $('html')[0] && event.clientX >= document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
      alert('vertical scrollbar clicked');
  })
})
```