# Disable Jquery function onclick of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrollbar

I would like to disable the piece of code in the stars in this function when my scrollbar gets clicked by the user.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

            *********setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php'); updateScroll();}, 1000);*********
            setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 1190);                
    });
```

It's a chat. When the user clicks the scrollbar in order to check out old messages, I don't want the updateScroll function to be called, which you can see within the stars. Any simple way?

Comment: um,.....is this a joke?  just delete it

Comment: Not a joke. As you can see, the updateScroll function updates every second. Thus, the chat gets populated with new messages and scrolls down every second. But for instance, say that a user wants to look at old messages and scrolls up, the function will still force the scrolling down every second. I don't want this to happen!

Comment: We can't even see a click Event.

Comment: Yeah....so like I said.  Delete it, or just copy and paste my answer below.  Either or.

Comment: The position of the onclick event is not relevant. IF I DELETE IT, the scrollbar will not scroll down everytime a user inserts a new message in the chat. I believe this is quite simple and clear

Comment: Just add an updateScroll() method, to when the user submits a message.  You are correct its simple and clear, which is why Im surprised its even a question.  Post the code, where the user submits a new message, and I'll add it to my answer.  So either you have the scroll happen every second (how you had it), or you update the scroll on submission of a new message.  Or keep it how you had it, and cancel the updateScroll when the user scrolls upwards.

Comment: See this SO answer on how to detect the scrollbar click. In that event handler clearInterval(). Now you just need to turn it back on when they scroll back down or mouse out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24369193/1245764

Comment: Set a global variable when they click on the scrollbar, and have the `setInterval` function check the variable before calling `updateScroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it....

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
     setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');  }, 1000); 
     setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 1190);                
});
```

Comment: This is part of my addmessage function, and it HAS a scrollbar in it. Still, it won't work:

' xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?uname='+uname+'&msg='+msg,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 100);'