# Bootstrap modal automatically closing on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using a niceScroll plugin in Bootstrap Modal. The plugin seems to work fine in everywhere except in Modal on IE. The issue is, on click and drag of the vertical Scroll Bar to scroll down when I release the vertical scrollbar the modal is automatically closing. I tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it did not work.

Please someone provide some input how to handle this behavior of modal scrolling issue.

```
angular.element('#contentDiv').niceScroll();
angular.element('#contentDiv').getNiceScroll().resize();


<div  id="sampleBubblediv"  ng-init="loadData()">
  <div id="contentDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The default behavior of a Bootstrap modal is to close when you click outside of the modal. Are you wanting to turn off this functionality entirely?

Comment: No I dont want to turn off this behavior but when i m using vertical scroll-bar to go down and the moment i release my mouse on scroll bar modal gets closed.

Comment: Is this scroll bar inside or outside of the modal?

Comment: Does it happen when you use the mouse wheel or arrow keys? if no, then IE is triggering a click event when you click on the scroll bar so you may need to look for a work around - if yes, then check your markup. I have had numerous weird bugs with BS modals because the markup required seems to change slightly in every release.

Comment: we are  using niceScroll plugin for scrolling and its generating inside the modal

Comment: @whiteatom you are absolutely correct its working fine with mouse wheel and arrow keys only on IE getting issue , please suggest some work around to fix it

Comment: Not too sure on the work around, but you know the issue now - so try searching that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have narrowed down to IE passing clicks on the scroll bar as body clicks, you need to search for that. Here is a work around for the issue.

[Determine whether user clicking scrollbar or content (onclick for native scroll bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045423/determine-whether-user-clicking-scrollbar-or-content-onclick-for-native-scroll)