# Differentiate user scroll from anchor scroll

Tags: javascript, html

In my Javascript code I'm listening for the scroll event and doing some work whenever it fires:

```js
document.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    (event) => {
        // do something
    },
    { passive: true }
);
```

I have a nav bar which contains anchors to different sections on my page, which when clicked causes the page to scroll down to the section (and fires the scroll event):

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-jump" href="#anchor-1">Popular Items</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

...

<section id="anchor-1">...</section>
```

However, I do not want the scroll event to fire when the page scrolls as a result of clicking on the anchor link. I only want it to fire when the user actually scrolls (i.e. with mouse wheel or by swiping).

I couldn't find any field in the 'event' object that would differentiate the two scroll sources but perhaps I missed something.

Answer (score 3):

The scroll event takes the most generic `Event` interface so there are no properties for differentiating the scroll source. I think it is basically unfeasible without completely overriding the default scroll anchor behaviour with your own JS. Having tried to do similar things in the past and ended up with horrible results, I would not recommend it.

You might want to think about doing this in reverse: disable anything you *don't* want to happen when a user clicks on the link, then renable it the next time a `wheel` or `touchmove` event is triggered. These events are particular to user scroll behaviour and won't be triggered by an anchor link.

```js
const link = document.querySelector("a");
const counter = document.querySelector("p");

let userScrolling = true;

link.addEventListener("click", () => userScrolling = false);

window.addEventListener("wheel", () => userScrolling = true);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", () => userScrolling = true);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => userScrolling = true);

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (!userScrolling) return;
  counter.textContent = parseInt(counter.textContent) + 1;
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

p {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.separator, #target {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#target">Link</a>
<p>0</p>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div id="target">Target<div>
```

You'll notice that there's a `mousedown` handler in there too. That's so we can enable user scrolling again by manually clicking and dragging the scrollbar, and also by clicking the middle-wheel compass. Unfortunately either one or multiple `scroll` events will still slip through depending on the browser if you use `mousedown` while the anchor scroll is in progress.

You could also go a step further to alleviate this issue and make sure the mouse event is from a middle wheel button `event.button = 1`, or is triggered over a scrollbar. This second factor is potentially complicated and beyond the scope of the question so I leave you with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61443583/12799351) which is the most promising I could find.

Honestly though, I think the takeaway here should be don't try to do this. The reason you can't distinguish user/anchor in the event is because they are functionally identical - a user clicking a button to scroll for them *is* user scroll behaviour and it should not realistically cause a problem. If you have some scroll-based animation you need to skip over, it might be better to just remove smooth-scrolling behaviour instead and reset the animation values in the background.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Does `wheel`, `touchmove` and `mousedown` cover all user scroll events? I've additionally added `keydown` and `keyup`.

Comment: first perfect cool trick that worked smoothly and was easy to implement , very underrated answer in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```js
let navElements = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[0]
let scroll = true

navElements.addEventListener("click", function () {
  scroll = false
});



document.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    (event) => {
        if ( scroll === true ) {
            // do something
        } 
        scroll = true
       
        
    },
    { passive: true }
);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-jump" href="#anchor-1">Popular Items</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

...

<section id="anchor-1">...</section>
```

## My approach

1. I initialize a element `scroll`, set to true.
2. I set another eventListener for the navbar link. Whenever it is clicked, scroll's value changes to false.
3. Then in your scroll eventListener, only do something if scroll === true, meaning it's not the nav-link that was clicked.
4. Lastly, I reset scroll's value to it's original state `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this approach doesn't work because scrolling takes time due to smooth scrolling which generates multiple events. Therefore on the 2nd+ event the `scroll` value is now true, thus the if condition within the handler evaluates to true and the body executes.